# Magento 2.3 - Salable Quantity turning off

Tags: magento2.3, quantity, msi

Is there a way to set work around the **Reservations in 2.3** ?

Currently,

> "The quantity of the product decrease only after shipping is
>   completed"

. We do oversell over the weekend as **qty** doesn't go down on order placement. Its brilliant but when you go back on Monday and see -45 on **products** you have a problem.

Can we switch so quantity depreciates on order placement?

Comment: How did you configured Admin > Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > Decrease Stock When Order is Placed = ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to third party extension that wasn't ready for 2.3

If anyone is using m2e and has this same issue: 
"you need to change configuration files so m2e takes a source from saleable quantity.
thanks,

Comment: Can you please explain the problem? I have the same issue but I'm not using m2e module...

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Krzysztof Linetty,

The behavior you described is quite strange. Because even so Magento decreases the Quantity of Product on Source only after shipping is completed, but along with that Magento creates Reservation at the time when the order is placed, and that reservation decreases Salable product quantity. So that the reservation mechanism prevents overselling, while admin will process the order.

You can read more about that here - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

Can you check whether you have reservations created for the orders you mentioned? and what is the Salable quantity of your product?

Comment: Thank you, this clear my confusion about Saleable Quantity.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free module by Ampersand, which does exactly that. It is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation). From the GitHub README:

> This module disables the inventory reservation logic introduced as part of MSI in Magento 2.3.3 - see https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2269 for more information about the way MSI was implemented, and the issues that can happen with external WMS integrations.
>
> This module will:
>
> - Prevent all writes to the `inventory_reservations` table. It does so by using an around plugin on `PlaceReservationsForSalesEventInterface`
> - Trigger stock deductions on order placement. See `inventory_sales_source_deduction_processor` observer on `sales_order_save_after` event.
> - Prevent stock deductions on order shipment. See disabled `inventory_sales_source_deduction_processor` observer on `sales_order_shipment_save_after event`.
> - Replenish stock for cancelled order items. See `inventory` observer on `sales_order_item_cancel` event.

Answer (score 0):

Go To Admin Left Menu Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Stock Options and Select 'Yes' for Selection 'Decrease Stock When Order is Placed'.

[image]

Comment: hi, i have the same setup. and order is depreciated after shipping is done.

Comment: @KrzysztofLinetty Maybe you have some kind of bug. The quantity should be decreased after checkout. There is no telling where the bug is in your store code unless this is a known Magento 2.3 bug